# Restart Windows service from Git Bash (MINGW64)

Tags: mingw, git-bash

It there a way to restart a Windows service inside a Git Bash script?

I'm dealing with a script (that loads a big dump) to make some temporary performance modifications in MySQL, and I need a last step that is:

1. Restart MySQL like this: `service mysql restart --innodb-doublewrite=0`
2. Import the data
3. Restart MySQL normally: `service mysql restart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Windows bash script should still be able to call Windows exe programs.

So try and call `/C/Windows/System32/sc.exe` (the [`sc` command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx)).
That will allow you to stop/start services.